# How to have javascript inside of react.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am building a React.JS website and I am not entirely sure how to implement a section of JavaScript inside of my html. In normal HTML you would put the script inside of these tags:

```
<Script></Script>
```

But with react.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
        <button onlick='log()'>Log</button>
        <script>
            Log() = Console.log('Hello')
        </Script>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Something like this will not work.
How am i able to run a script this way?

Comment: You can try `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` - but keep in mind it's called "dangerously" for a good reason. Do you really need to return a script tag though? Probably not.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 function App() {
const log =()=> {console.log('Hello')}
  return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={()=>log()}>Log</button>
     
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

more information: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 1):

Please learn how React works and how [events work specifically](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

#### A basic example:

```
function App() {
  const log = () => console.log('Hello')

  return <button onClick={log}>Log</button>
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This code re-declares the `log` function on every re-render. It works, but not ideal. Better to put the `log` statement outside the functional component. Not a problem with your answer, just sharing for anyone reading this.

Comment: @Slbox - This is the norm in React functional development and is meaningless in terms of performance. What you **should have** mentioned is that a *new function* is created every time which `log` refers to, which can be avoided using the `useCallback` hook, which I did not include not to confuse OP.

Answer (score 0):

no need to use script tag you can put all the functions you want inside the App function and before return
please specify what you need to do exactly so i can help

Comment: At the moment I am just trying to find out how to implement a script. I have no exact need for it at the moment. I am just playing around at the moment trying to get to grips with it

Comment: ok so you only need to put the script inside the function App and before return function

Comment: please write this as a comment and not as an answer

Answer (score 0):

[ReactJs Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) will be your friend here but basically you can run your javascript code inside your function component before your return statement

Here is a [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-keller-0ql08?file=/src/App.js) example

Answer (score -2):

This is a better approach, but there's a lot you have to learn about React from your code in your question, beyond what I think I can explain in this answer. Your code has a number of typos and you probably do not actually need to use a `<script>` tag.

```js
const logger = () => {
  console.log('hello')
}

function App() {
    return (
      <div>
          <button onClick={logger}>Log</button>
      </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I know quite a bit, but i was just putting in something basic at the moment as a placeholder for the script code, i know that it was not correct

Comment: you wrote a **functional** component and not a Class, but mix the two together in your answer, which results in an invalid code.

Comment: @vsync good catch. Lots of typos in the original code made it easier to make a mistake

Comment: @LukeC your code isn't basic, it's just wrong. `Console` is not the proper casing. `onlick='log()'` is not remotely correct React code. There's nothing wrong with needing to learn, but please understand how much you have to learn.